# What does the equal '=' actually do in rust (with/without 'let')?

Tags: rust, binding, compiler-construction, assign

I am confused when rust do the memcpy and calls the drop functions. I read some related pages but did not find a detailed description of this.

Here are some simple codes:

```
struct MyType {
    name: String,
    age: i32
}

impl MyType {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let tmp = MyType {
            name: String::from("Joy"),
            age: 1
        };

        let addr = &tmp as *const MyType as usize;
        println!("Calling new.");
        println!("tmp : name: {}, age: {}", tmp.name, tmp.age);
        println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);

        tmp
    }
}

impl Drop for MyType {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Calling drop.\n");
    }
}

fn main() {

    println!("");

    let a = MyType{
        name: String::from("Tom"),
        age : 10
    };
    let addr = &a as *const MyType as usize;
    println!(" a  : name: {}, age: {}", a.name, a.age);
    println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);

    let mut b = a;
    let addr = &b as *const MyType as usize;
    println!(" b  : name: {}, age: {}", b.name, b.age);
    println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);

    b = MyType::new();
    let addr = &b as *const MyType as usize;
    println!(" b  : name: {}, age: {}", b.name, b.age);
    println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);

    let c = MyType::new();
    let addr = &c as *const MyType as usize;
    println!(" c  : name: {}, age: {}", c.name, c.age);
    println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);

    b = c;
    let addr = &b as *const MyType as usize;
    println!(" b  : name: {}, age: {}", b.name, b.age);
    println!("addr: 0x{:X}\n",addr);
}
```

And outputs:

```
> Executing task: cargo run --package hello_world --bin hello_world <

   Compiling hello_world v0.1.0 (/home/dji/proj_learn_rust/hello_world)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.21s
     Running `target/debug/hello_world`

 a  : name: Tom, age: 10
addr: 0x7FFDB8636AF0

 b  : name: Tom, age: 10
addr: 0x7FFDB8636BE0

Calling new.
tmp : name: Joy, age: 1
addr: 0x7FFDB8636CB8

Calling drop.

 b  : name: Joy, age: 1
addr: 0x7FFDB8636BE0

Calling new.
tmp : name: Joy, age: 1
addr: 0x7FFDB8636DB0

 c  : name: Joy, age: 1
addr: 0x7FFDB8636DB0

Calling drop.

 b  : name: Joy, age: 1
addr: 0x7FFDB8636BE0

Calling drop.
```

1. After `let mut b = a;`, it seems that the addresses of `a` and `b` are not the same. Why not directly transfer the memory of `a` to `b` when executing the **move** operation, since `a` is no longer valid? It seems that a shallow copy (as memcpy in C) was made when using the `let` keyword, without calling drop function.
2. The addresses of `c` and `tmp` are the same. At this time, it seems that the real **move** was executed instead of the memcpy, without calling drop function.
3. But why does `b = c;` call the drop function while `let mut b = a;` and `let c = MyType::new();` do not?

Is the `let` avoiding drop calling?

Comment: You don't use `--release` flag to enable optimizations. Unoptimized code behave almost in the same way as the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the short answer: the `let` is not avoiding drop calling, it is used to introduce new variables.
`=` without `let` is simple variable assignment.

### The Long Answer

1. Whenever you specify a variable in your code, the compiler has to allocate memory for storing the variable's value at runtime.
   So for each of `a`, `b`, and `c`, the compiler has to allocate a memory location.
   That is the reason why `a` and `b` have different addresses.
   `let mut b = a` moved the **value** from memory location `a` to memory location `b`.
   After that move, `a` can no longer be used.
2. `c` and `tmp` are not part of the same function.
   Additionally, only one of `c` and `tmp` can be in scope at any time, so they can reuse the same memory location.
3. In `let mut b = a`, `b` has no value yet.
   Therefore, there is nothing to `drop`.
   In `b = MyType::new()`, however, `b` already contains the value, that was assigend to it in `let mut b = a`.
   This value is then dropped.
   You can verify this by changing the `Drop` implementation of `MyType` to print the name of the dropped value.
   Similarly, `c` does not yet contain a value in `let c = MyType::new()`.
   In `b = c`, however, `b` already contains the value assigned to it in `b = MyType::new()`, which has to be dropped first.

For further explanations, you can check the Rust reference for [let statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#let-statements) and [assignment expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#assignment-expressions).
The documentation of the [`Drop` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) could also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Every time you calling a function, it allocates new frame on stack. When function exits, it's frame drops. That's why you have different addresses with `a` and `tmp`. Probably, if you will compile with `--release` flag that may change, because compiler can inline function calls or perform many other optimizations.
2. You are not calling `new` function, so everything is happening in the same stack frame. That's why compiler may just reassign variables without any actual actions with the memory.
3. The difference between two examples it that in the second example your `b` is already own a value (previously created on line `b = MyType::new();`). So this value should be dropped after assigning from `c`. In other words it drop not `b`'s value, but actually previously created with line `b = MyType::new();`.